# What does it mean 'upstream' in the manifest file, repo?

Tags: android, git, manifest, repo

I found the 'upstream' attribute in manifest file, repo.
I'm not sure what it means during 'repo sync' and 'repo sync -c'
And what's the difference between projectA and projectB below example.

During 'repo sync', I think it will clone projectA with commit '12345',
In projectB case, it will also clone projectB with commit 'abcde'.
Why 'upstream' is needed?

Please could you explain what it means?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest>
    <project name="projectA" path="project/A" remote="aosp" revision="12345" upstream="projectA/develop"/>
    <project name="projectB" path="project/B" remote="aosp" revision="abcde" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: `Upstream:` can find a SHA1 in which git branch. Used to synchronize revision locked manifest (-c mode). This model can avoid synchronization of the whole ref space.

Comment: The upstream is a Git ref, including branches, tags, Gerrit's `refs/changes/xx/yyyy/z` or any valid refs. It tells repo to fetch this ref and then checkout `revision`. If `-c` is specified in `repo sync`, only this upstream will be fetched. If `revision` is already a ref, then checkout the ref. Specifically, when the revision is a branch, repo always checks out the latest commit of the branch. See https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/+/master/docs/manifest-format.txt

Comment: @ElpieKay Thank you for your explanation. Now I understand what it means.

Answer (score 2):

Attribute upstream as defined in [repo Manifest Format](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/+/master/docs/manifest-format.md#:%7E:text=A%20repo%20manifest%20describes%20the,in%20the%20top%20level%20directory.)

> Attribute upstream: Name of the Git ref in which a sha1 can be found. Used when syncing a revision locked manifest in -c mode to avoid having to sync the entire ref space.

From this I understand that the sha mentioned in *revision="12345"* can be found in branch *develop*

I am guessing that there is some default entry at the top of manifest which will help the second line in your snippet.